# Lost connection to forge in eclipse

Tags: modding, eclipse

So I am using eclipse to make mods for Minecraft. I recently took a break and was doing other things. My problem is when I came back to it, all my work was gone. There is nothing in the file explorer. The only changes I made to my computer between now and the last time I used eclipse is that I cleaned up my desktop (I moved a few related files into other folders) and that I installed a program called MCreator (to help with a class I'm teaching, and it may have messed with some of the related files). Does anyone have any idea what would have caused it and/or how to fix this?

Comment: probably an issue with Gradle.
Ask in esper#minecraftforge

Comment: What is that? A stack exchange site?

Comment: IRC, its normally pretty active.